# Divided geom_smooth after using pipe operator

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a problem related to pipe operator in ggplot2. My dataset is "iris" and my code is:

```
iris %>% 
mutate(petalPlus = as.factor(ifelse(Petal.Length > 5.5, 1, 0))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, col = Species, shape = 
petalPlus)) + 
geom_point() +
theme_bw() +
geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

The problem is that what I get are 4 linear regression lines (for every color and shape). I would like to know how to obtain one regression line and what is the reason why currently I get 4 lines.

Comment: Try to take/remove `col = Species` & `shape = petalPlus` out of `aes` and see what will happen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 colour geom\_point by factor but geom\_smooth based on all data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562859/ggplot2-colour-geom-point-by-factor-but-geom-smooth-based-on-all-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 4 lines because `geom_smooth` inherits the `shape` and `col` `aes` from the `ggplot` call, and they define implicitly a `group` `aes`.

To avoid it either define the `aes` in each geom, or define them only in `geom_smooth`, disabling the inheritance:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% 
  mutate(petalPlus = as.factor(ifelse(Petal.Length > 5.5, 1, 0))) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Length,
                 y = Petal.Width, 
                 col = Species, 
                 shape = petalPlus)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width), method = "lm")
```

[image]

```r
iris %>% 
  mutate(petalPlus = as.factor(ifelse(Petal.Length > 5.5, 1, 0))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, 
             y = Petal.Width, 
             col = Species, 
             shape = petalPlus)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width), method = "lm", inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3):

It's not due to your use of the pipe operator, but rather due to having all your `aes` specifications together. That implies to the `geom_smooth` function that you want different lines of all combinations of color and shape. One way to do this is is to reverse the order of the geom calls and have their separate  `aes`'s tailored to your specifications:

```
png()
print(
 iris %>% 
mutate(petalPlus = as.factor(ifelse(Petal.Length > 5.5, 1, 0))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + 
   theme_bw() +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
   geom_point(aes(col=Species,shape=petalPlus))
 dev.off() )
```

[image]