Do linear regression with all points not separated by hue
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = category)) +
    geom_point() +  
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "black")    

This does the linear regression separately for each category. I would like to color the points differently, but use ALL the points for the linear regression (just one linear regression).
What can I change to achieve this?

No it's generating 2 lines, 1 for each category.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/16562859/13203906

This question is similar to: ggplot2 colour geom_point by factor but geom_smooth based on all data. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To generate one regression line but still have the points colored you can pass color to geom_point instead of globally
library(ggplot2)
library(palmerpenguins)


ggplot(penguins, aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = species)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', color = 'black')
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite outside the scale range
#> (`stat_smooth()`).
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_point()`).


Created on 2024-08-30 with reprex v2.1.1
